# -Wambiguous-fields raised on field selectors of same type

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just updated a project to GHC 9.2.4 and some modules raise the `ambiguous-fields` warning.
Reading about `-XDuplicateRecordFields`, I understand it is necessary to disambiguate same field names in different types when used as selectors.

But this code:

```
import Data.Aeson

customDefaultOptions :: Options
customDefaultOptions = defaultOptions {omitNothingFields = True}

newtypeOptions :: Options
newtypeOptions = customDefaultOptions {unwrapUnaryRecords = True}
```

Also raises it:

```bash
    The record update customDefaultOptions
                        {unwrapUnaryRecords = True} with type Options is ambiguous.
    This will not be supported by -XDuplicateRecordFields in future releases of GHC.
   |
 7 | newtypeOptions = customDefaultOptions {unwrapUnaryRecords = True}
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Yet, `customDefaultOptions` is of type `Options`, like `defaultOptions`, where is the ambiguity?

Comment: That's strange.  I can't duplicate on GHC 9.2.4 using `aeson-2.1.0.0` with this minimal example.  Is there a custom `Data.Aeson` module involved?

Comment: Good question!  
`aeson-2.0.3.0` on my side but I found that `openapi3-3.2.2`,which is also used in same module, exposes a very similar `defaultSchemaOptions` sharing a lot of field names.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [K. A. Buhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203016/k-a-buhr), I found that `openapi3` exposes a very similar structure.

Prefixing field with its module name disambiguate it:

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson

newtypeOptions :: Options
newtypeOptions = customDefaultOptions {Aeson.unwrapUnaryRecords = True}
```